# AVAudioPlayer BluetoothA2DP disconnection / connection

Tags: ios, bluetooth, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avaudioengine

I am currently struggling with an issue. When using AVAudioPlayer or player nodes connected to an AVAudioEngine when a BluetoothA2DP device disconnects and the players are started again there is no audio, however the players are "playing". Additionally this works as expected with regular headphones.

Any ideas or insights into whats going on here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's strange - how is your `AVAudioSession` configured? Are you listening for `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification`s? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MediaPlaybackGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/RefiningTheUserExperience/RefiningTheUserExperience.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016757-CH6-SW12

Comment: I am listening and I had tried a few things but it’s not a lot of help if you do not know the right action to take sadly. The guide doesn’t help and like I said above this is not a problem with regular headphones.

Comment: Additionally the session is configured as playback, duck others and allows Bluetooth and BluetoothA2DP